# How to put a space between two outputs when time delay is used in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Currently I am using a barometric sensor with a raspberry pi. I am using a time delay and my code looks something like this,

```
import smbus
import time

while True:
try:
# Get I2C bus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# BMP280 address, 0x76(118)
# Read data back from 0x88(136), 24 bytes
b1 = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x76, 0x88, 24)

# Convert the data
# Temp coefficents
dig_T1 = b1[1] * 256 + b1[0]
dig_T2 = b1[3] * 256 + b1[2]
if dig_T2 > 32767 :
    dig_T2 -= 65536
dig_T3 = b1[5] * 256 + b1[4]
if dig_T3 > 32767 :
    dig_T3 -= 65536

# Pressure coefficents
dig_P1 = b1[7] * 256 + b1[6]
dig_P2 = b1[9] * 256 + b1[8]
if dig_P2 > 32767 :
    dig_P2 -= 65536
dig_P3 = b1[11] * 256 + b1[10]
if dig_P3 > 32767 :
    dig_P3 -= 65536
dig_P4 = b1[13] * 256 + b1[12]
if dig_P4 > 32767 :
    dig_P4 -= 65536
dig_P5 = b1[15] * 256 + b1[14]
if dig_P5 > 32767 :
    dig_P5 -= 65536
dig_P6 = b1[17] * 256 + b1[16]
if dig_P6 > 32767 :
    dig_P6 -= 65536
dig_P7 = b1[19] * 256 + b1[18]
if dig_P7 > 32767 :
    dig_P7 -= 65536
dig_P8 = b1[21] * 256 + b1[20]
if dig_P8 > 32767 :
    dig_P8 -= 65536
dig_P9 = b1[23] * 256 + b1[22]
if dig_P9 > 32767 :
    dig_P9 -= 65536

# BMP280 address, 0x76(118)
# Select Control measurement register, 0xF4(244)
#       0x27(39)    Pressure and Temperature Oversampling rate = 1
#                   Normal mode
bus.write_byte_data(0x76, 0xF4, 0x27)
# BMP280 address, 0x76(118)
# Select Configuration register, 0xF5(245)
#       0xA0(00)    Stand_by time = 1000 ms
bus.write_byte_data(0x76, 0xF5, 0xA0)

time.sleep(0.5)

# BMP280 address, 0x76(118)
# Read data back from 0xF7(247), 8 bytes
# Pressure MSB, Pressure LSB, Pressure xLSB, Temperature MSB, Temperature     LSB
# Temperature xLSB, Humidity MSB, Humidity LSB
data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x76, 0xF7, 8)

# Convert pressure and temperature data to 19-bits
adc_p = ((data[0] * 65536) + (data[1] * 256) + (data[2] & 0xF0)) / 16
adc_t = ((data[3] * 65536) + (data[4] * 256) + (data[5] & 0xF0)) / 16

# Temperature offset calculations
var1 = ((adc_t) / 16384.0 - (dig_T1) / 1024.0) * (dig_T2)
var2 = (((adc_t) / 131072.0 - (dig_T1) / 8192.0) * ((adc_t)/131072.0 -     (dig_T1)/8192.0)) * (dig_T3)
t_fine = (var1 + var2)
cTemp = (var1 + var2) / 5120.0
fTemp = cTemp * 1.8 + 32

# Pressure offset calculations
var1 = (t_fine / 2.0) - 64000.0
var2 = var1 * var1 * (dig_P6) / 32768.0
var2 = var2 + var1 * (dig_P5) * 2.0
var2 = (var2 / 4.0) + ((dig_P4) * 65536.0)
var1 = ((dig_P3) * var1 * var1 / 524288.0 + ( dig_P2) * var1) / 524288.0
var1 = (1.0 + var1 / 32768.0) * (dig_P1)
p = 1048576.0 - adc_p
p = (p - (var2 / 4096.0)) * 6250.0 / var1
var1 = (dig_P9) * p * p / 2147483648.0
var2 = p * (dig_P8) / 32768.0
pressure = (p + (var1 + var2 + (dig_P7)) / 16.0) / 100

# Output data to screen
print "Temperature in Celsius : %.2f C" %cTemp
print "Temperature in Fahrenheit : %.2f F" %fTemp
print "Pressure : %.2f hPa " %pressure 
    # add a short sleep here at the end...
    sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
# quit
    sys.exit()
```

The above code gives me outputs of temperature in Celsius, temperature in Fahrenheit and pressure with a delay of one second in the following format.

```
Temp in C
Temp in F
Pressure
Temp in C
Temp in F
Pressure
Temp in C
Temp in F
Pressure
```

I want to put a gap (and I want to control this gap) between each sets of outputs when I use a loop and a time delay in this case (something like a line break). My output should look something like this,

```
Temp in C
Temp in F
Pressure

Temp in C
Temp in F
Pressure

Temp in C
Temp in F
Pressure
```

I can understand that by putting print (") will give a line space but is there any way to adjust the size of this line space? For example if the line space is of 1 cm, then how can we change it/ make it to 0.5 cm or 2 cm? Any guidance will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Is a block of output (with all 3 variables) produced from a single `.read_i2c_block_data()` ? Or does each .read_i2c_block_data()` returns only 1 of those variables ?

Comment: no there is a block of output which produce all 3 variables at a time.

Comment: ok then it is simple, just print an empty line after you print your 3 variables. Just `print()`

Answer (score 1):

you can print empty line right before or after sleep(1) `print()`

Comment: Is there any way to adjust this gap? For example if the empty line is of size 1 cm, then how can I make it to 0.5 cm or 2 cm? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @John: that raises a question: how do you print your altitude, pressure and temperature variables ? Show us the code please, by editing your question

Comment: @John line height is related to your console font-name and font-size, so maybe you could manipulate them (make size bigger or smaller) right before printing empty line and them revert those setting back. If it is not possible you could only increase height of gap - print more than one empty line - ```1-empty-line-height * times-your-print-it```

Comment: @Guilaume: I have now added the whole code and did the modification with the post.